# nginx error connect to php5-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: unix, nginx, php

I update nginx to **1.4.7** and php to **5.5.12**, After that I got the **502 error**. Before I update everything works fine.

nginx-error.log

```
2014/05/03 13:27:41 [crit] 4202#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xx.xx, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx"
```

nginx.conf

```
user  www www;
worker_processes  1;

        location / {
            root   /usr/home/user/public_html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }
        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /usr/home/user/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
```

Comment: This bug report explains why this is happening: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67060

Comment: Everyone coming here from a ubuntu 14 to 16 upgrade you need to change the sock to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 check if /usr/home/user/public_html permision and user is the same in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf , /etc/nginx/conf.d/www.conf and other config files like php - everywhere user should be the same in my case

Answer (score 666, accepted):

I had a similar error after php update. PHP fixed a [security bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67060) where `o` had `rw` permission to the socket file.

1. Open `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` or `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, depending on your version.
2. Uncomment all permission lines, like:

   ```
   listen.owner = www-data
   listen.group = www-data
   listen.mode = 0660
   ```
3. Restart fpm - `sudo service php5-fpm restart` or `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`

**Note**: if your webserver runs as user other than www-data, you will need to update the `www.conf` file accordingly

Comment: Given that this makes the socket writable to absolutely everyone, I can't help but think that this is a horrible solution.

Comment: This approach restores the insecure default configuration resolved in https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67060 - consider instead the listen.owner fix suggested by artooro.

Comment: Very confusing. Why not edit your answer to be correct, (Go to /etc...) and then afterwards comment about how there is a less secure way that only works till reboot (Go to /var/..).

Comment: Reopen a fixed bug is not a valid solution for me. artooro solution it's more appropriate and secure.

Comment: @Tecnocat Why it less secure? I think they are the same. www-data and 660. So, I don't understand what's wrong?

Comment: I believe this solution is as secure as artooro's, however setting the listen.mode is not necessary. I suspect 0660 is the default setting for listen.mode anyway.

Comment: `sudo usermod -aG www-data nginx` allows nginx to access the file

Comment: If the server is running, how can we know which user is running `nginx` ??

Comment: I only uncommented `listen.mode = 0660` as both `listen.owner = www-data` and `listen.group = www-data` were already uncommnented.

Comment: It's not working in my case. I uncommented `listen.mode = 0660` as other two were already uncommented.

Comment: How can an answer that says, almost in clear text __"break the security fix to get things working"__ have so many upvotes?

Comment: @berbt What do you mean? 0660 - is a default permission anyway.

Comment: For those using remi, the `www.conf` file is in `/opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

Comment: php-fpm.sock can not find after uncommented listen.group and listen.owner

Comment: should also check if you have multiple pools with different listen.owners and listen.groups make sure the Nginx user (for example www-data) is a member of the listen.group secondary group. So if a FPM pool is owned by bob:

listen.owner = bob
listen.group = bob
Add the user www-data as a member of secondary group bob

usermod -G bob www-data

Comment: Also run sudo service nginx restart in case if this doesn't work.

Comment: This two lines worked for me (after create folder /var/php/):
  `listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`
  `listen.acl_users = apache,nginx`

Comment: I got this warning after setting listen.user and listen.group
" WARNING: [pool www] ACL set, listen.owner = 'www-data' is ignored"

I re-commented-out listen.user and listen.group and un-commented and modified
listen.acl_users = www-data
listen.acl_groups = www-data

Answer (score 114):

All the fixes currently mentioned here basically enable the security hole all over again.

What I ended up doing is adding the following lines to my PHP-FPM configuration file.

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

Make sure that www-data is actually the user the nginx worker is running as. For debian it's www-data by default.

Doing it this way does not enable the [security problem that this change was supposed to fix](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67060).

Comment: This is the correct solution. The change in default configuration comes from https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67060 and appears in Debian https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2014-0185

Comment: To check the nginx username `ps aux|grep nginx`

Comment: On Ubuntu at /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

Comment: @RealityExtractor I don't think so. That file only contains general PHP settings, nothing related to the FPM process manager.

Comment: For me, I also had to manually delete `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`, since it was already created by `www-data`. Just a heads-up...

Comment: This is the proper fix, security-wise.

Comment: @RealityExtractor that file is not the right one, as @Martijn Heemels says. In Debian, probably Ubuntu too, you have to edit `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`. Recent PHP-FPM versions include the configuration lines `listen.owner`, `listen.group` by default, no need to add them.

Comment: For `nginx` just make sure you have `user www-data` in your `nginx.conf` file to fix this.

Comment: thank you, this worked for me. On CentOS 7, the user and group, both were `nginx`

Comment: Double check the permissions of the socket file. Note, that to `reload` the PHP-FPM process may not (!) change the socket's permission according to the settings in the `pool.d/....conf` file (`listen.owner`). In this case it may be necessary to `chown` the socket file manually.

Comment: worked in oracle linux 8 with user nginx

Answer (score 47):

@Xander's solution works, but does not persist after a reboot.

I found that I had to change `listen.mode` to `0660` in  `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.

Sample from www.conf:

```
; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions. 
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0660
;listen.owner = www-data
;listen.group = www-data
;listen.mode = 0660
```

**Edit:** Per @Chris Burgess, I've changed this to the more secure method.

I removed the comment for listen.mode, .group and .owner:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

/var/run Only holds information about the running system since last boot, e.g., currently logged-in users and running daemons. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure).

**Side note:**

My `php5-fpm -v` Reports: `PHP 5.4.28-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1`. The issue did happen after a recent update as well.

Comment: This approach restores the insecure default configuration resolved in https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67060 - consider instead the listen.owner fix suggested by artooro.

Comment: If `listen.acl_groups` is set, `listen.owner` and `listen.group` are ignored. 
 I set `listen.acl_groups =`, then the 502/permissions problem went away.  Found it after uncommenting the `listen.` lines as above, the 502 problem persisted and `systemctl status php-fpm` showed the warning `WARNING: [pool www] ACL set, listen.owner = 'nobody' is ignored`.

Answer (score 41):

If you have tried everything in this post but are not having success getting PHP to work, this is what fixed it for my case:

Make sure you have these lines uncommented in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

Make sure /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params looks like this:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

These two lines were missing from my /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params, make sure they are there!

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;
```

Then, restart php5-fpm and nginx. Should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was losing all my hopes, this saved my ass.

Comment: You're my hero, you saved the day!

Comment: There are no words that can describe how grateful I am! After updating packages everything went kaput and this saved the day.

Comment: I want to give you more than one +

Answer (score 31):

In fact, "listen.mode" should be: "0660" and not "0666" as Other Writable or Other Readable  is never a good choice here.

So try to find out as which user/group your webserver runs. I use CentOs and it runs as user "nginx"
So add to your php-fpm.conf:

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

finally restart php-fpm

Comment: For what it's worth, on my Ubuntu 12.04 system, the user and group are `www-data`.

Comment: For me in CentOS, it worked to set the user as "nobody" and the group as "nginx".  Probably not a major improvement, but I'd prefer to give as limited of permissions as possible.

Answer (score 30):

Check which user runs nginx. As of Ubuntu 12.04 nginx runs by nginx user which is not a member of www-data group.

> usermod -a -G www-data nginx

and restarting nginx and php5-fpm daemons solves the problem.

Comment: This fix seems to be the cleanest, security wise.  Worked on Ubuntu 14.04, Nginx 1.7.10, PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 (fpm-fcgi)

Answer (score 17):

Alternative to broadening permissions in your php config, you could change the user specified in your nginx config.

On the first line of your nginx.conf excerpt above, the user and group are specified as www and www, respectively.

```
user  www www;
```

Meanwhile, your php config probably specifies a user and group of www-data:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

You might change the line in your nginx.conf, to any of the following, then:

```
user www-data www;
user www-data www-data; # or any group, really, since you have the user matching
user www www-data; # requires that your php listen.mode gives rw access to the group
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Change nginx.conf is necessary.

Answer (score 15):

I had the similar error.

All recommendations didn't help.

The only replacement www-data with nginx has helped:

```
$ sudo chown nginx:nginx /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
```

/var/www/php/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
...
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

Comment: Hey @Alexander,

You need to use chown command to change the owners to nginx. This really helped me a lot.

Comment: Sure, I used chown, there was a mistake in the comment, thanks

Comment: This also works for php 7.4. Thanks.

Comment: what is nginx isn't a user

Comment: This works on Centos 7 and php-fpm 7.4

Answer (score 11):

The problem in my case was that the Nginx web server was running as user nginx and the pool was running as user www-data.

I solved the issue by changing the user Nginx is running at in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file (could be different on your system, mine is Ubuntu 16.04.1)

Change: `user nginx;`

to: `user www-data;`

then restart Nginx: `service nginx restart`

Answer (score 7):

Consideration must also be given to your individual FPM pools, if any.

I couldn't figure out why none of these answers was working for me today. This had been a set-and-forget scenario for me, where I had forgotten that listen.user and listen.group were duplicated on a per-pool basis.

If you used pools for different user accounts like I did, where each user account owns their FPM processes and sockets, setting only the default listen.owner and listen.group configuration options to 'nginx' will simply not work. And obviously, letting 'nginx' own them all is not acceptable either.

For *each pool*, make sure that

```
listen.group = nginx
```

Otherwise, you can leave the pool's ownership and such alone.

Comment: Thank you. If Ngnix works for different user accounts, should be changed like this "listen.group = nginx"

Answer (score 6):

I just got this error again today as I updated my machine (with updates for PHP) running **Ubuntu 14.04**. The distribution config file `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` is fine and doesn't require any changes currently.

I found the following errors:

```
dmesg | grep php
[...]
[ 4996.801789] traps: php5-fpm[23231] general protection ip:6c60d1 sp:7fff3f8c68f0 error:0 in php5-fpm[400000+800000]
[ 6788.335355] traps: php5-fpm[9069] general protection ip:6c5d81 sp:7fff98dd9a00 error:0 in php5-fpm[400000+7ff000]
```

The strange thing was that I have 2 sites running that utilize PHP-FPM on this machine one was running fine and the other (a Tiny Tiny RSS installation) gave me a 502, where *both* have been running fine *before*.

I compared both configuration files and found that `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` was missing for the affected site.

Both configuration files now contain the following block and are running fine again:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
}
```

## Update

It should be noted that Ubuntu ships two fastcgi related parameter files and also a configuration snippet which is available since Vivid and also in the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/ubuntu/development) version. The solution was updated accordingly.

Diff of the fastcgi parameter files:

```
$ diff -up fastcgi_params fastcgi.conf
--- fastcgi_params      2015-07-22 01:42:39.000000000 +0200
+++ fastcgi.conf        2015-07-22 01:42:39.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@

+fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
 fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
 fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
```

Configuration snippet in `/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf`

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have the same problem. It`s weird that in package not included this line. I just add it to /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params and all works again now.

Answer (score 6):

The following simple fix worked for me, bypassing possible permissions issues with the socket.

In your nginx config, set fastcgi_pass to:

```
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Instead of

```
fastcgi_pass   /var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

This must match the listen = parameter in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf, so also set this to:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Then restart php5-fpm and nginx

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

And

```
service nginx restart
```

For more info, see: https://wildlyinaccurate.com/solving-502-bad-gateway-with-nginx-php-fpm/

Comment: While this may get one up and going, it is not a solution for fixing a sock issue.

Answer (score 4):

Simple but works..

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx

chown nginx:nginx /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```

Comment: As I understand, this won't survive a reboot, so is more of a temporary fix.

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed  same issue on Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09 (Centos 7) by taking following steps.

Open your **www.conf** files (Example : sudo nano /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf)
Lastly, find the lines that set the listen.owner and listen.group and change their values from "nobody" to "nginx":

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0666
```

Lastly, find the lines that set the user and group and change their values from "apache" to "nginx":

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

Restart php-fpm (sudo service php-fpm restart)

Comment: Use 660 instead 666. 666 is insecure and was fixed by this patch https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=67060&patch=mode660&revision=latest

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing here is wich user is using nginx then do you need specify it as well

in your nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

        location / {
            root   /usr/home/user/public_html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }
        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /usr/home/user/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
```

in your www.conf

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
;listen.mode = 0660
```

in your case the user and group is "www" so just replace it.

- restart nginx and php fpm

Answer (score 3):

Just see `/etc/php5/php-fpm.conf 
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid` IS PID file

In file `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

`listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` IS SOCKET file

if you pid equal listen (`pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock and listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`) -> wrong settings
and finish sett `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, on CentOS (and probably Red Hat and Fedora) the file to change the permissions to is at:

> /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

Answer (score 2):

If you have different pool per user make sure user and group are set correctly in configuration file. You can find nginx user in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file. nginx group is same as nginx user.

```
user = [pool-user]
group = [pool-group]
listen.owner = [nginx-user]
listen.group = [nginx-group]
```

Answer (score 2):

Also check SELINUX (/etc/selinux):

```
# getenforce
```

turn it off:

```
# setenforce 0
```

Comment: You should never opt to reduce the security of a system to get something working, rather use one of the many options in the other answers to solve your issue. Do not disable selinux without extremely good reason to do so!

Answer (score 2):

In my case php-fpm wasn't running at all, so I just had to start the service

```
service php7.3-fpm start
#on ubuntu 18.04
```

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 lts to Ubuntu 16.04 lts I found a yet another reason for this error that I haven't seen before.

During the upgrading process I had somehow lost my php5-fpm executable altogether. All the config files were intact and it took me a while to realize that `service php5-fpm start` didn't really start a process, as it did not show any errors.

My moment of awakening was when I noticed that there were no socket file in `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`, as there should be, nor did `netstat -an` show processes listening on the port that I tried as an alternative while trying to solve this problem. Since the file /usr/sbin/php5-fpm was also non-existing, I was finally on the right track.

**In order to solve this problem I upgraded php from version 5.5 to 7.0.** `apt-get install php-fpm` did the trick as a side effect. After that and installing other necessary packages everything was back to normal.

---

*This upgrading solution may have problems of its own*, however. Since php has evolved quite a bit, it's possible that the software will break in unimaginable ways. So, even though I did go down that path, you may want to keep the version you're fond of just for a while longer.

Luckily, [there seems to be a neat way for that](https://thecustomizewindows.com/2016/05/paths-in-nginx-php-7-fpm-ubuntu-16-04-vs-14-04-php-5/), as described on The Customize Windows site:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get purge php5-common
apt-get update
apt-get install php5.6
```

Neater solution as it might be, I didn't try that. I expect the next couple of days will tell me whether I should have.

Answer (score 1):

All right here:

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

But change here too:

```
; When set, listen.owner and listen.group are ignored
listen.acl_users = apache
;listen.acl_groups =
```

Comment this line:

```
; When set, listen.owner and listen.group are ignored
;listen.acl_users = apache
;listen.acl_groups =
```

Answer (score 0):

I did change OS on my server quite a few times trying to get the most comfortable system.

It used to work very well most of the time but lastly I got this 502 Gateway error.

I use a php fpm socket for each account instead of keeping the same one for all. So if one crashes, at least the other applications keep running.

I used to have user and group www-data. But this changed on my Debian 8 with latest Nginx 1.8 and php5-fpm.

The default user is nginx and so is the group. To be sure of this, the best way is to check the /etc/group and /etc/passwd files. These can't lie.

It is there I found that now I have nginx in both and no longer www-data.

Maybe this can help some people still trying to find out why the error message keeps coming up.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To those who tried everything in this thread and still stuck: This solved my problem.
I updated /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

1. Uncomment the line saying `user`
2. make it `www-data` so it becomes: `user www-data;`
3. Save it (root access required)
4. Restart nginx

Answer (score 0):

If you have declarations

> pid = /run/php-fpm.pid

and

> listen = /run/php-fpm.pid

in different configuration files, then root will owner of this file.

Answer (score 0):

Please **NOTICE** (**at least in centos 8**) the user who you are assigning `listen.owner` and other stuff to it **MUST**
be in the same **POOL** with the user for example given I am the **foo** user

```
[www] # WRONG | IN MY CASE I WAS UNDER www POOL SO IT WASNT WORKING FOR ME.
[foo] # CORRECT | THE POOL AND THE USER MATCHES.

listen.owner = foo
listen.group = foo
listen.mode = 0660
user = foo
group = foo
```

I dont know if there's a global pool but after hours of searching I finlly did it.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was **unix:** directive before PHP-FPM listen socket define  `/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock` inside `www.conf` file
my simple Nginx config file php block looks like this

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /home/mysuser/www;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
```