# Nginx forward to tomcat failing

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx

I was trying to forward my nginx server to tomcat (on the same server).

I followed the following tutorials:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-tomcat-8-connections-with-apache-or-nginx-on-centos-7

But it still doesn't seem to work, although it did on my previous server.

Here is my nginx configuration

```
....

Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

upstream tomcat {
server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  mywebsite.be demo.mywebsite.be;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
       #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    proxy_pass http://tomcat/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    ....
```

When I restart nginx and go to my website, I get the following error:

"The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later."

While my tomcat server is online and working.

I have no idea what is going wrong, I already reinstalled nginx and tomcat a couple of times.

The nginx error logs gives the following errors

```
2017/12/09 13:33:53 [crit] 1288#0: *73 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to
     upstream, client: 87.**.***.244, server: mywebsite.be, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0
    .1:8080/", host: "demo.mywebsite.be"

2017/12/09 13:33:53 [crit] 1288#0: *73 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to
 upstream, client: 87.**.***.244, server: mywebsite.be, request: "GET /nginx-logo.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "
http://127.0.0.1:8080/nginx-logo.png", host: "demo.mywebsite.be", referrer: "https://demo.mywebsite.be/"

2017/12/09 13:33:53 [crit] 1288#0: *74 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to
 upstream, client: 87.**.***.244, server: mywebsite.be, request: "GET /poweredby.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "h
ttp://127.0.0.1:8080/poweredby.png", host: "demo.mywebsite.be", referrer: "https://demo.mywebsite.be/"

2017/12/09 13:33:53 [crit] 1288#0: *74 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 87.**.***.244, server: mywebsite.be, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: "demo.mywebsite.be", referrer: "https://demo.mywebsite.be/"
```

Comment: If your site is generating a 5xx response, there should be a corresponding message in the error log.

Comment: Thanks, I added the nginx error logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Richard Smith for the idea of the error log

I have solved this by running the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect true
```

Like explained on:

[nginx proxy server localhost permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235453/nginx-proxy-server-localhost-permission-denied)