# Nginx PHP5.6 permission eror

Tags: php, nginx

I am getting the following error in my Nginx error.log file, what do I need to do to prevent this from happening?

> 2016/06/28 09:43:37 [crit] 1631#0: *1 connect() to
>   unix:/run/php/php5.6 fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while
>   connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.56.1, server: my-vm, request:
>   "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock:", $host: "my-vm-1"

Nginx runs with www-data permissions. The permissions of the folder that the error message is referencing (`/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock`) are as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x 20 root       root         700 Jun 28 09:45 run
drwxr-xr-x 2  www-data   www-data     80  Jun 28 09:44 php
srw-rw---- 1  www-data   www-data     0   Jun 28 09:44 php5.6-fpm.sock
```

The user/group of PHP (`/etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`) is:

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

The `nginx.conf` file does not have any `user` value set. Some people have suggested setting this to `www-data`, but if I set this the Nginx service won't start, hence why it is ommitted.

Comment: This question seem to already exist here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443398/nginx-error-connect-to-php5-fpm-sock-failed-13-permission-denied

Comment: one solution is use nginx as user in nginx config and add user nginx to www-data group

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding the following user directive to the **top** of my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data www-data;
```