# nginx and SSL: 502 bad gateway

Tags: ssl, nginx

I really hope you guys can help me out. I lost my way around different guides of setting up ssl.

When I try to access my site i just get `502 Bad Gateway`. Plain old nginx works just fine, and "simple" ssl without forces ssl also works fine.

Here are my config files.

default.conf

```
## http://xn--srentorp-54a.dk redirects to https://xn--srentorp-54a.dk
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name xn--srentorp-54a.dk;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://xn--srentorp-54a.dk$request_uri;
    }
}

## http://www.xn--srentorp-54a.dk redirects to https://www.xn--srentorp-54a.dk
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name www.xn--srentorp-54a.dk;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.xn--srentorp-54a.dk$request_uri;
    }
}

## https://xn--srentorp-54a.dk redirects to https://www.xn--srentorp-54a.dk
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name xn--srentorp-54a.dk;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xn--srentorp-54a.dk/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xn--srentorp-54a.dk/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xn--srentorp-54a.dk/fullchain.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.xn--srentorp-54a.dk$request_uri;
    }
}

## Serves https://www.xn--srentorp-54a.dk
server {
    server_name www.xn--srentorp-54a.dk;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server ipv6only=on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xn--srentorp-54a.dk/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xn--srentorp-54a.dk/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xn--srentorp-54a.dk/fullchain.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;


        root /var/www/;
        index index.html index.php;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
        }
            location ~/\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name torpinc.xn--srentorp-54a.dk;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_connect_timeout 150;
                proxy_send_timeout 100;
                proxy_read_timeout 100;
                proxy_buffers 4 32k;
                client_max_body_size 8m;
                client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name perpt.xn--srentorp-54a.dk;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_connect_timeout 150;
                proxy_send_timeout 100;
                proxy_read_timeout 100;
                proxy_buffers 4 32k;
                client_max_body_size 8m;
                client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        }
}
```

letsencrypt.conf

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        default_type "text/plain";
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
}
```

ssl.conf

```
sl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EECDH+AES;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is an etiquette around asking questions which you can read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Your question is simply a code dump and "this isn't working", which makes it really hard to offer a solution without spending a large amount of time to try and reproduce the problem. Please provide more information about where you think the problem is and what you have tried

Comment: Thank you for your response @mikkel. I would like to give you more information, I just dont know what information you need.

Is there any log etc. I could provide you with?

Comment: I solved the problem. It was related to this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443398/nginx-error-connect-to-php5-fpm-sock-failed-13-permission-denied