# Ubuntu 16.04, nginx, phpmyadmin - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin

I am using this setting for nginx (default file):

```
server {
        listen 30425;

        # Don't want to log accesses.
        #access_log  /dev/null main;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/php.acces_log main;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/php.error_log info;

        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        error_page 401 403 404 /404.php;

        location ~ .*.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $http_host;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;

        }
}
```

When I try to access 30425, I am getting **502 Bad Gateway**. All other setting are default one (PHP 7).

Comment: So open logs and read them.

Comment: Look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/14560181/2549588 Same as your situation

Answer (score 4):

I had to replace this fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000; 
to fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
and then it worked perfectly.

Full code.

```
server{
    listen 80;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    location / {
            #try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
            autoindex on;
    }


    location ~\.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+);
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_na$
            fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $http_host;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
    }
```

}

Comment: moved from php 7.3 to 7.4 , but did not chage fastscgi_pass version. Thank you